# How to select an internship topic from a set of suggested topics?

Tags: research-topic, internship

How would a student best select a topic among several suggested especially if it's her/his first time doing an internship and the internship period is short (2 months or 6 months)?

What are important things to consider?

Also, any suggestions to select an internship topic that would contribute to the skills needed to work in the industry (i.e. purely academic versus industry-related topic)?

PS: The topics suggested are accompanied with a select of corresponding papers.

Comment: If I were the student, I'd read the list of topics, look at some of the corresponding papers, and see whether any of the topics or papers makes me say to myself "Hey, I really want to look into this more deeply." If so, then I'd choose the topic that excites me the most. Working on a project is much easier if I feel that I really want to learn the topic than if I feel that I'm obligated to learn it because it's my job. (Fortunately, I get enthusiastic about mathematical ideas quite easily and spontaneously.)